# can't pull images from AWS ECR to docker in on-prem ubuntu server

Tags: docker, amazon-ecr, on-premises-instances

I logged into the my aws account and has admin access, once i configured aws I generated a password using key/secret and use the same password to pull images from ECR.

I am trying to pull the images from my aws ECR to docker but it waits for some time and throws error `error pulling image configuration: download failed after attempts=6: Filtered`

If a try pulling a image which doesn't exist it shows the error message correctly
`The repository with name 'mongos' does not exist in the registry with id '###########'`

I have a proxy through which the connection to aws goes. I also configured the https/http proxy in docker level.

Let me know what i am missing

I tried different approaches still no luck